# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf failed to stream my invoice it just keep loading in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to stream my invoice. But when i click to stream it just keep loading it is not responding;
this is my function

```
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('receipt', array('user' => $user, 'traveller'=>$cus_info));
  return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: can you check do you need to provide parameter to stream method (file name that you want to stream)

Comment: no parameter needed.

Comment: maybe then problem is in the view. is that correct path to blade file? resources/views/receipt?

Comment: this is the correct view I put when I add resources and views it throws errors view not found.

Comment: Enable `show_warnings` in `config/dompdf.php`, it may help.